Can I change the layout of Joomla subform fields without an override?

The fields in my subform allow a field class.
I thought I could add something like col-md-12 to get a field to take up the full width.  It didn't work.
So then I added row to the subform, but I can only add it to the subform field.
Then I tried using a CSS attribute:
td[data-column="     Case Study Information "]
But it strips out the spaces in CSS and I can't stop Joomla adding them in the source code!
I'm guessing all this means I need to do an override, but I would have thought there was an easier way to control the layout of the subforms rather than them all being in a row.

In the subform field, you have inside the Options tab the layout param, with 3 different layout. Did you checked that? Also, if you have the default layout for the subform, that layout do not render any custom css class, you can see for yourself in layouts\joomla\form\field\subform\default.php

Ah I had not looked but in the sourcecode I could see it I thought.  I can do an override, I just figured there might be an easier way.

You have 3 possible options for the "layout" argument of subform:

joomla.form.field.subform.default render the subform in a div container, without support of repeating. Default for single mode.
joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable render the subform in a div container, used for multiple mode. Support groupByFieldset.
joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table render the subform as a table, used for multiple mode. Supports groupByFieldset. By default each field is rendered as a table column, but if groupByFieldset=true then each fieldset is rendered as a table column.

(see https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type for full description)
Looks like yours is set to joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table. Try joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable instead for the classic full-width Joomla look.

Welcome to Joomla Stack exchange and thanks for your comprehensive answer and supporting link.  Is one of those items supposed to say row?
